# Ionic 3, Angular 4 and prepopulated database

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

After follow several tutorials, I find imposible to use a prepopulated SqlLite in Ionic 3 and Angular 4..
I try this plugins, all with the same result..

cordova-plugin-dbcopy

nativescript-sqlite

Cordova-sqlite-storage

cordova-sqlite-ext

Anyone here did it?.. if so.. how? I only find tutorials with ionic 2 or 1..

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 3 and 2 are basically the same framework.
You can follow the tutorial.
What you need is clearly this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

Its show how to install "Cordova-sqlite-storage" for ionic 2/3.

Comment: It only works if you are going to create a new database and you populate from the app..